# is Foursquare herenow items down?

Tags: web-services, api, foursquare

I am used to get check-ins with

> https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4b64c88af964a520d4cf2ae3/herenow?oauth_token=XXXXXXX&v=20120725

but yesterday, I realize that my app is not working properly. I can not get the items[](people who cheked in specific venue). Web service retrieving json like this;

```
{
   meta: {
   code: 200
}
notifications: [
{
  type: "notificationTray"
  item: {
  unreadCount: 0
}
}
]
response: {
hereNow: {
  count: 16
  items: [ ]
}
}
}
```

Comment: really a good question to ask. I have problems with that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seriakillaz is right -- the behavior you're seeing is intentional, and is described by the email he links to.

In general though, the hereNow *is* working as before if you're checking into a place (the official foursquare apps use the same endpoints we document publicly).

If you're having trouble with it after accounting for the new policy, checkout my response to seriakillaz question: 
[hereNow not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646322/herenow-not-working-as-expected/11655103#11655103)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, even if I checked in a place where some people already cheked in, still I can not retrieve their information with hereNow service.

Comment: I added a note to seriakillaz question, looks like the problem might be that you're not passing in the lat/long of the checkin. Here's the Edit I left.

**Edit:** A couple other devs have run into this issue, and in many cases, it looks like the issue is that lat/lng isn't being passed into the checkins/add request (the "ll" param). You're not included in hereNow unless you're deemed to be plausibly close to the venue.

Answer (score 1):

They've just changed the hereNow endpoint: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/foursquare-api/rmS0DbKKOHo

However it is not working for me even if I check-in to a place...