# hereNow not working as expected

Tags: api, foursquare

I've got that they changed their api according to this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/foursquare-api/sQMuHlv9wiU

But it sais I should be able to get people near-by if I'm checked-in to the specific place. However it gives me back the same response before check-in and after check-in ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** A couple other devs have run into this issue, and in many cases, it looks like the issue is that lat/lng isn't being passed into the checkins/add request (the "ll" param). You're not included in hereNow unless you're deemed to be plausibly close to the venue.

You should be able to get other people checked into the venue after having checked in, but remember, there might not always be other people checked in.

In general, for the venue you've checked in at, you should see roughly the same number of people listed in the hereNow block as the "count" field shows. However, people can opt out of showing up in hereNow, so you will still occasionally see fewer people than the count field shows.

Remember that you're only considered "checked in" to a venue if (a) it's been less than 3 hours since you checked in and (b) you haven't checked in anywhere else.

If you're still having problems, email api (at) foursquare.com with the specific request to hereNow made before checking in, the request you made to check in, followed by the request to hereNow you made after checking in, and we can help you debug.